# Application insights profiling NodeJs application using Docker image

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, azure-application-insights

I want to know if Azure App insights support profiling for Nodejs Apps. If not the case, is there any alternative for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if Azure App insights support profiling for Nodejs Apps.

Yes, you can perform profiling for Node.js apps using Azure Application Insights.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=nodejs), install the following client libraries:

```
npm install @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base
npm install @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node
npm install @azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter
```

You can refer to [Monitor your Node.js services and apps with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs), [Use Application Insights with on-premises Node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772725/use-application-insights-with-on-premises-node-js-application) and [Need help and guidance for accessing operationId in nodejs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955110/need-help-and-guidance-for-accessing-operationid-in-nodejs-application)

For more information, you can check the GitHub repository of [Application Insights SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js)